# Opencart Multistore

Tags: opencart

I have recently set up a multistore for a few different subdomains. I was notified by email that I received a few orders on one of the subdomains but I am not seeing those orders in the opencart admin.

So my question is, how do I view orders in the opencart admin for multistore subdomains?

Comment: which plugin is used for Multistore?

Answer (score 1):

Multistore orders are not in any way different to your regular orders. They should show alongside your default store ones. The easiest way to check this is to go to SALES > ORDERS and change the status filter to `Missing Orders` and click the filter button. If they're in there then the payment method isn't working correctly. If they aren't, then you've not set up multistore properly and contact a professional to do this for you

Answer (score 1):

Missing orders do not send email. I would suggest you go to Sales > Orders and check what is the latest. Then go to settings and see where did you put the e-mail which received the order emails and do the link. Consider testing an order yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to check this is to go to

**SALES > ORDERS**

and change the

**Order Status**

filter to Missing Orders and click the filter button.

If they're in there then the payment method isn't working correctly.

You can see below pictures for the better understanding for you:

[image]

You've not set up multistore properly, you may need to contact a professional to do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Multistore in opencart is same as single store. Login to admin then navigate to SALES > ORDERS. All orders will be listed there except the missing order. To view the missing order change the order status filter to Missing Orders and click the filter button to check missing orders.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a script or payment method with some delay causing the problem and causing orders to fall as Abandoned.
Check that the email is working correctly and that the payment methods are fully functional, or check the console to see if there are any script errors.
Test some orders with other payment methods and see how it works.